# How to create an auto scroll?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, automation, e-commerce, product

This is the product page of my ecommerce website. https://www.myhealingcrystalstore.com/beta/product/abundance-bracelet/

Its is built on woocommerce. I would like a add an auto scroll to the recommended products once the user adds product to their cart. I would really appreciate if I could get a guidance on how I can achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

as your page is reloading after adding to cart, you can do it with LocalStorage.
Try this and use different conditions as per your requirements.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button").on("click", function(e){
    localStorage.setItem('add_to_cart', 'clicked');
});
var add_to_cart_clicked = localStorage.getItem('add_to_cart');
if(add_to_cart_clicked == 'clicked'){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(".hongo-woocommerce-tabs.hongo-woocommerce-tabs-wrapper").offset().top
    }, 2000);
 }
}
```

Let me know if you need more help, thanks

Comment: Hey, I am using woocommerce so can you please guide me on where I should add this. Like via a plugin or something.

Comment: Yes, you can use a plugin to add this code in Js file. Just install "custom css js" plugin and create a js file with it and add above code in that file. Make sure you select load in footer options from the plugin. thanks